# Default arithmetic operators in C#

Tags: c#

How does c# define +,-,*,/ operators for classes who don't have the operators overloaded? I have implemented the following class. Without overloading any operators, the mentioned operators work, and they work the way I was going to implement! 
Here's the code:

```
class Number
{
    private float mDecimal;
    public float Decimal
    {
        get { return mDecimal; }
    }

    private int mOrder;
    public int Order
    {
        get { return mOrder; }
    }

    public Number(float dec, int pow)
    {
        mDecimal = dec;
        mOrder = pow;
    }

    public Number Power(Number number)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static implicit operator Number(float num)
    {
        int pow = 0;
        while (num > 1000)
        {
            num *= 0.1f;
            ++pow;
        }

        return new Number(num, pow);
    }

    public static implicit operator float(Number num)
    {
        float result = num.mDecimal;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.mOrder; ++i)
            result *= 10;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now take in account this piece of usage code:

```
Number n1 = 5;
Number n2 = 10;
Number n3 = n1 + n2;
```

**n3** evaluates to 15! This happens with other operators too!

Comment: It's because you've defined the `implicit operator float` - so the `+` operator will implicitly convert your values from `Number` to `float` (`System.Single`), perform the addition, then convert back.

Comment: Didn't you even try placing a break point in the implicit operators, which were the only possible reason this worked?

Comment: @Andrew I'm new to c#. My background is c++ which does not work these kinds of situations implicitly. So without knowing the type, since **Number** is convertible to float, it uses the float? I placed other conversion operators for another custom class, but it uses the float operators again. How does the compiler choose which conversion to do to provide arithmetic operators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`n3 = n1 + n2` is evaluated as follows:

1. First, the list of candidate operators is determined, including any user-defined overloads ([ECMA-334, section 14.2.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)). None apply, so the set of candidate operators becomes the predefined binary operator `+`. Had you defined your own `operator+(Number, Number)` this is where it would have been selected. (You probably do want to implement it to prevent rounding errors from back-and-forth converting.)
2. Now overload resolution kicks in to determine which implementation of `+` should be used (section 14.4.2). This is probably the most complicated part of the C# spec, but we don't need to delve into it very deeply -- all we need is the knowledge that implicit conversions apply when selecting an appropriate overload (14.4.2.1). For the precise rules, you'll also need to read section 13.4 on user-defined conversions.
3. The language treats user-defined implicit conversions on an even footing with built-in conversions. In this case, because there is an implicit conversion from `Number` to `float`, the only candidate overload for `+` remaining after resolution is `float operator +(float, float)` with implicit conversions, so that is invoked.
4. The resulting `float` is then implicitly converted to `Number` by use of the other operator. Note that even without this, you would still get a `float` addition, the result just wouldn't convert back. The compiler does not actually "lift" the operator, though the effect is much the same (lifting does happen for nullable versions of value types, but that's another story).

When mixing types that have implicit conversions, things can get tricky. Overload resolution tries very hard to do the Right Thing and the rules are unambiguous, but even so it can be hard to see when a conversion is involved, so don't overuse implicit conversion operators. Explicit conversions require a bit more keystrokes, but it's also much easier to tell what operator will end up being invoked. This is certainly true when you're initially developing the type so you can check which operators you haven't yet implemented (but need to, for performance or precision reasons).

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer one would benefit from, in more than one way.