# C#: Find out result type of arithmetic operations in code (e.g. int + double = double)

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to come up with a function to determine the result type of arithmetic operations, say for the case of addition:

```
Type TypeOfAddition(Type leftType, Type rightType)
{
  // ???
}

Type TypeOfMultiplication(Type leftType, Type rightType)
{
  // ???
}

// ... same for subtraction and division
```

These desired result of these functions is probably clear; Essentially, my goal is do to the same (at runtime) that Visual Studio does when inferring types to "var"-type variables when doing arithmetic operations.

For example,

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string operator +(MyClass left, double right)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

TypeOfAddition(typeof(int), typeof(double)); // Should return typeof(double)
TypeOfAddition(typeof(string), typeof(int)); // Should return typeof(string)
TypeOfAddition(typeof(MyClass), typeof(double));  // Should return typeof(string)
```

My base idea was an implementation like, conceptually

```
Type TypeOfAddition(Type leftType, Type rightType)
{
  return leftType.GetMethods().Single(x =>
    x.Name == "op_Addition" &&
    x.GetParamters().Count == 2 &&
    x.GetParameters().Last().ParameterType == rightType);
}
```

but

A) This won't work for base types like int, double etc., which don't seem to explicitly define operator overloads, and

B) The above linq clause won't catch all cases yet (e.g. inheritance)

I could hard-code the base types and try to come up with a smart solution for B) as well, but that seems relatively .. unelegant.

Is there any smarter / easier / good solution to solving this?
Mind you, I only want to get the theoretical type of the result of such an operation, without actually executing an arithmetic operation explicitly.

Thanks!

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table help? It shows which types will be 'coerced' to other types (which is basically what you need).

Comment: Why do you even want to do this in the first place?  This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @mjwills Thanks - it does help a lot in case I have to go for the hard-coded way!

Comment: This is anything but easy. Specifically, overload resolution is part of the language/compiler logic, and the only run-time representation I know of lives in `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder`. Leveraging that is not easy since most of it is deliberately not documented (you're supposed to just use `dynamic` and not worry about it). The overload resolution rules of C# with regards to operators are [hideously complex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41083899/), so unless your set of possibilities is strictly limited I advise against reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Juharr basically for a type of formula parser/calculator, so want to check whether result of a certain operation is valid input for another operation etc.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks! That is.. discouraging but very helpful both at the same time :-) Will look into RuntimeBinder for a start

Comment: @Bogey Then I suggest you ask about that instead as people might give you ideas of how to handle it that doesn't require the complexity of how you're attempting to solve that problem.

Comment: Probably have to spin up Roslyn and ask it to compile a small sample (using `default` for the values) and then ask for the result type of the expression.

Comment: @Bogey: if at all possible, define your own language for this parser/calculator, and don't say "it uses the same rules as C#", because you're making life really difficult for yourself if you do. If you want that you're better off driving the entire compiler programmatically in that case (per @Damien), which is quite doable with Roslyn, but possibly overkill. Still better than selectively reimplementing parts.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, will think that through again. From gut feeling I don't think I can take a shortcut on this as e.g. aiming to allow plugins to export formula functions that need to be able to return custom types (think of something like Excel formulas.. main app provides a =SUM() function, a plugin might export a formula function that returns a custom type, which in turn overloads the + operator .. the formula parser would try to infer compatibility & type of result of a =SUM(1.234, PluginFunction()) call ahead of execution

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, good idea - maybe I can try using the scripting APIs for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly isn't pretty, and definitely isn't fast, but it appears to work with the basic tests I've ran it through.

Note that you'll need to have `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` referenced.

```
Type TypeOfAddition<TLeft, TRight>()
{
    object GetDefault<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));
    }

    var binder = Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.BinaryOperation(
        CSharpBinderFlags.None,
        ExpressionType.Add,
        null,
        new CSharpArgumentInfo[] {
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
        }
    );

    var left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLeft));
    var right = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRight));

    var func = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Dynamic(binder, typeof(object), left, right),
        new[] { left, right }
    ).Compile();

    return func
        .DynamicInvoke(GetDefault<TLeft>(), GetDefault<TRight>())
        ?.GetType() ?? typeof(object);
}
```

Example outputs:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string operator +(MyClass left, double right)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

TypeOfAddition<string, int>().Dump();     // System.String
TypeOfAddition<int, double>().Dump();     // System.Double
TypeOfAddition<float, double>().Dump();   // System.Double
TypeOfAddition<MyClass, double>().Dump(); // System.String
```

This uses what Jeroen mentioned in the comments (RuntimeBinder) to create a addition binder.  It then builds a dynamic expression tree to add the default values of both `TLeft` and `TRight`.  I had to add a small function called `GetDefault` to resolve `string` to an empty string, since I'm assuming you want to see `string` when trying to add `"" + 0` instead of `null`.  If you *do* want to see nulls, just replace the `GetDefault` calls with `default(TLeft)` and `default(TRight)`.

It doesn't call constructors (due to using [`GetUninitializedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject(v=vs.110).aspx)) contains a special case for strings.

There are likely many possible improvements, and I am all ears.

Comment: This creates values at runtime, though, which is fine for `int` and `double` but less so for `MyClass` (which has a default of `null`, and besides, we wouldn't want to invoke the constructor, including possible side effects).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion / work, appreciate it! This doesn't seem to work for me with custom types, e.g. of passing MyClass (see first post) it would throw at dynamicinvoke because it can't create a default. If explicitly creating one (via GetDefault), the returned type would be the runtime type too instead of declared type, e.g. if defining  MyClass operator +(MyClass left, MyClass right) { return null; }  , the function would return typeof(object) instead of typeof(MyClass)

Comment: @Bogey I modified the `GetDefault` method to now return an instance of reference types, which calls the operator overload.  Still not sure how to handle non-default constructors, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Scott! Great approach. I've posted a Roslyn-based approach below which avoids the constructor restriction, but has quite a few other downsides. Still wonder if there's any way at all to use your/the Binder approach without that restriction somehow, but couldn't figure anything out so far

Comment: `return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));` should possibly be replaced with `new T()` (and then add new constraint to the function declaration).

Comment: @mjwills I actually started with that, but `string` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, meaning it couldn't be passed in as a type.

Comment: @Bogey I think I've got it!  We can (ab)use [`GetUninitializedObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the instance *without calling constructors*.  I've never played with Roslyn myself, but your solution is still very interesting, nice work!

Comment: Great point - I didn't know that @Scott - thanks for sharing!

Comment: Amazing, thanks @Scott ! Extremely clever solution! Only very tiny pitfall I'm seeing so far is that it actually executes the operation with dummy values (only an issue if some oddly expensive work is done in there, which shouldn't be the case anyway), and that it returns the actual runtime type of that result. so in cases like return (right == default(double)) ? new DerivedOne() as MyClass : new DerivedTwo() as MyClass;  it would return typeof(DerivedOne) instead of typeof(MyClass), even though operation result will not always be DerivedOne. BUT ...

Comment: @Scott ... just something to maybe be aware of for future reference; these shouldn't be any issues in my case and I much prefer this over the Roslyn way! Thanks again - will mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

Using Roslyn, I now came up with the following. So far from what I tested, it seems to work fine - let me know what you think.

Downsides (no major issue in my case though) from what I see are

- Somewhat slow, at least on first call
- Must explicitly reference assemblies. Not sure if this triggers these to be re-loaded into whatever AppDomain/context Roslyn scripts use, if so, might slow this down a bit further for many/large assemblies
- Obviously need to use/deploy a lot of Roslyn assemblies with my app just for this

  ```
  static async Task<Type> GetOperationResultTypeAsync(Type left, Type right, string operatorSymbol)
  {
      // Reference all assemblies that are loaded in the current AppDomain (plugins?)
      var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
      var script = CSharpScript.Create($"var instance = default({left.FullName}) {operatorSymbol} default({right.FullName});", options: options);

      var compilation = script.GetCompilation();
      var syntaxTree = compilation.SyntaxTrees.Single();
      var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

      var variableDeclaration = (await syntaxTree.GetRootAsync())
          .DescendantNodes()
          .OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>()
          .Single();

      var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(variableDeclaration.Type);
      var typeSymbol = (ITypeSymbol)symbolInfo.Symbol; // will be null on error (eg operation not possible/defined/allowed)

      if (typeSymbol == null)
          return null;

      var symbolDisplayFormat = new SymbolDisplayFormat(typeQualificationStyle: SymbolDisplayTypeQualificationStyle.NameAndContainingTypesAndNamespaces);
      string fullyQualifiedName = typeSymbol.ToDisplayString(symbolDisplayFormat);

      Type type = Type.GetType(fullyQualifiedName, throwOnError: true);
      return type;
  }
  ```

with usage just being

```
Type t1 = await GetOperationResultTypeAsync(typeof(MyClass), typeof(double), "+");
Type t2 = await GetOperationResultTypeAsync(typeof(int), typeof(int), "+");
Type t3 = await GetOperationResultTypeAsync(typeof(int), typeof(double), "+");
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try Generics in your methods. Something like

```
Type TypeOfAddition<T, T2>(T leftNum, T2 rightNum){
    var result = leftNum + rightNum;
    return typeof(result);
}

Type TypeOfMultiplication<T, T2>(T leftNum, T2 rightNum){
    var result = leftNum * rightNum;
    return typeof(result);
}
```

Comment: Generics and math operators don't mix at all. You won't be able to compile code containing `+`.

Comment: Well, even so, I bet it will be easier to supply the method typed variables and get the type of a dynamically typed result than doing it straight with types.

Comment: Maybe you could try encapsulating the basic type with a collection, like List, and then use just its first index.