# C# usual arithmetic conversions - result/operand types of arithmetic operations?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, arithmetic-expressions

In C# arithmetic operations on number types can result in a value with a different type than either of the operands. Take the following snippet for example:

```
byte x = 10;
byte y = 20;
var z = x + y;
```

Here z will be `int`.

My questions would be:

1. What are the exact rules governing the type conversions? I couldn't find resources on C# (or .NET in general). However it seems that the rules are the same as in C/C++, thus the ones on this page apply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/usual-arithmetic-conversions
2. Which operators are affected, and do any of them have special rules? It seems to me that +, -, *, /, %, &, |, ^, <<, >> behave the same way with `byte` operands at least. However the decompiled source code (done with ILSpy) shows differences: explicit `int` casts are added for both operands only for division and remainder, and the second argument of shifting is cast to `int` (but this latter is explicitly stated [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator) too); no other `int` cast anywhere.
3. Do I understand correctly that results will be computed with the converted operands, i.e. there can be implicit type conversions, even if not apparent from the decompiled code? (Following [implicit numeric conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table).) So if we have a `var z = (short)(x + y);` line that will be equivalent to `var z1 = (short)((int)x + (int)y);`? It seems so because if `x` and `y` are both 255 then the result `short` will be 510 (i.e. out of range for `byte`).

I'd like to programmatically determine (when the original operand types and the operator is given) what the converted operand and result types will be. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486364/c-find-out-result-type-of-arithmetic-operations-in-code-e-g-int-double-d) touches on this but doesn't shed light on the rules.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that, that's not the question, but rather what rules govern these conversions.

Comment: The [C# language specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/tree/master/spec) is the definitive place to find this information. You have to look at both the operators as well as implicit conversions, since the compiler is allowed to insert them for both operands before calling the operator.

Comment: @mike z I'm hoping for some table for example, like the C, instead of me trying to stitch together a ruleset. But you're right, this can definitely be constructed from the language specification.

Comment: @PetSerAl all the possible ones.

Comment: Don't use var.  var should only be used when you can't use standard types like with linq results.  Too many people are too lazy to actually put real types in their code.  When adding two bytes together the plus sign in c# converts everything to int automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Find out result type of arithmetic operations in code (e.g. int + double = double)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486364/c-find-out-result-type-of-arithmetic-operations-in-code-e-g-int-double-d)

Comment: @jdweng I think it is reductionist to state that `var` is primarily about laziness.

Comment: I have a more practical solution. This is an XY problem because the reason you want the table is to look up what the type of the result will be. If you hover over the operator, you can see which one its going to use - no need to look it up in a table.

Comment: @PetSerAl "numeric promotions" seems to be the term I missed, thank you. I think the reference you linked is what I was looking for, so that solves my question! Care to add it as an answer?

Comment: @Richardissimo The reason I was looking for a table is because I'm working on a tool that needs to analyze a C# AST and generate code from it (https://hastlayer.com/) so sometimes we need to know the exact language rules. I'm not having trouble writing binary operator expressions in VS.